# Nuget and adding package to solution

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Is it possible to add package to Visual Studio solution via nuget without adding this package to any project, but keep this package in "packages" folder only ?

Comment: `Install-Package Nuget.Downloader` then just fetch the package you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution to your question is creating a solution-level package such as NuGet.Commandline package. The solution-level package will be downloaded into the packages folder as well; it just won't change anything to the projects.

What is the difference between a project-level package and a solution-level package?

A solution-level package has to be installed only once in a solution to be available for all projects in the solution. A project-level package must be installed separately in each project where you want to use it. For solution-level packages, NuGet doesn't change anything in a project, whereas in a project-level package it does. Typically, a solution-level package installs new commands that can be called from within the Package Manager Console window.